# Azure Load Testing: How to add 20k test files into my test?

Tags: azure, azure-load-testing

I have created a JMeter test that randomly selects orders from a pool of 20K .json data files.
I need to upload the .json files along with the .jmx file, however, the Azure Load Testing UI allows the upload of 10 files at most.

I have read the documentation and I could not find anything relevant on how to upload the 20k data files.

Is there a way to upload the 20k files to my test in one go?
Thanks,
P.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that there is an Azure Load Testing API that I can use to upload my data files.

More information can be found in the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loadtesting/dataplane/test/upload-test-file?tabs=HTTP

Thanks,
P.